# Unresponsive Server - But only from dev machine

Tags: networking, hosting, server

This problem has been driving me insane. I have a several different sites across a few unique hosting environments. Intermittently, when I try to browse one of these sites from my main development machine (MacBook), it's either incredibly slow or connections time out. The same site loads perfectly fine from other machines and from Pingdom.

**Here are the facts.**

- The timeouts can occur on accessing both static and dynamic content.
- The problem comes and goes. It's seemingly random.
- Traceroutes seem to crap out on po1.fcr01.sr01.dal05.networklayer.com (Even on a machine where the site is working fine)
- In chrome, the waits are labeled as a TTFB.
- The problem occurs on sites on at least three different IPs, from two different hosting providers.
- My ISP is Google Fiber. The offending machine is a year-old MacBook Pro running 10.9.5

If anyone could give me ideas of things to check or what you think might be going on, that would be incredible.

Answer (score 0):

developer tools and plugins can tend to slow things down. You might try turning off all your plugins and then turning them back on one by one.